# random holes and islands of UV unwrap with seams. how to fix?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, faces

I have a model that was made using photogrammetry software. So an algorithm created the mesh. The model is like a cube in that it has a top, bottom, and four sides.

I import  the .obj into Blender and want to unwrap the mesh for a texture.

I have marked seams. everything is ok....except:

When I unwrap the mesh the subsequent uv map has random holes in the middle of mesh on various sides. The faces in the holes are still in the uv map, but are grouped into several islands of their own off to the side.

The following image shows the mesh close up( left ) and the uv map ( right ). the orange selected faces demonstrate how they are being placed into random islands off to the side of where they should be.

[image: overall view of uv map on right. and selected faces of 'hole' in up map left.]

Followed by a close up of the uv map and the hole where the selected faces should be.

[image: close up of up map showing hole]

How do i get these faces to connect where they should in the uv map? thus filling the holes.

and any idea what causes this?

**Thank you.**

** overall view of the front and back of the model:

[image: front of model]
[image: back of model]

Comment: Check that your object are [manifold](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry/7914#7914)